# how can i swap two nodes without exchanging data

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, swap, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {   
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;

void createnodeatbeg(int key) {
    struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = key;
    new->next = head;
    head = new;
}

void printlist() {
    struct node *temp = head;
    printf("list is:");
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d  ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void swapnodes(int x, int y) {
    struct node *prevX = NULL;
    struct node *prevY = NULL;
    struct node *currX = head;
    struct node *currY = head;
    while (currX->data != x && currX != NULL) {
        prevX = currX;
        currX = currX->next;
    }
    printf("not found\n");
    while (currY->data != y && currY != NULL) {
        prevY = currY;
        currY = currY->next;
    }

    if (currX == NULL || currY == NULL) {
        printf("elements not found\n");
        return;
    }
    struct node *swap = currY->next;
    prevX->next = currY;
    currY->next = prevY;
    prevY->next = currX;
    currX->next = swap;    
}

int main() {    
    head = NULL;
    int nodes, key;
    printf("enter number of nodes\n");
    scanf("%d", &nodes);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        int data;
        printf("enter number\n");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        createnodeatbeg(data);
    }
    printlist();
    int x, y;
    printf("enter the values from the list to be swapped\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    swapnodes(x, y);    
    printf("swapped list is:\n");
    printlist();
}
```

My code works when elements (x and y) are present in the list but if it is not present in the list then error is `./a.out terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`.
The problem is that the control doesn't comes out of the first while loop in `swapNodes()` function.
The code takes a user input and creates a node at the beginning.

Comment: Apart from what @cse mentioned there is a bug in swap logic also if it swaps first and last node. Do some paper work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in following identical lines:

- `while(currX->data!=x && currX!=NULL)`
- `while(currY->data!=y && currY!=NULL)`

This is because instead of fist checking for `NULL` and then use it, you are checking for `NULL` latter. So when `x` or `y` is not present then you are trying to access `NULL->data`, which is giving *Segmentation Fault Error (SIGSEGV)*

Change it to following respectively:

- `while(currX!=NULL && currX->data!=x)`
- `while(currY!=NULL && currY->data!=y)`

Comment: cse's solution works, because when the left part of a "and" is false (which makes the "and" false), the right part is not tested.

Comment: It would be nice also to reference the name of this concept, "short-circuit logic operators" or "short-circuit evaluation" [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 2):

The order of operands in the conditions of the while statements is wrong.

```
while(currX->data!=x && currX!=NULL)
{
    prevX=currX;
    currX=currX->next;
}
//...
while(currY->data!=y && currY!=NULL)
{
    prevY=currY;
    currY=currY->next;
}
```

Here must be

```
while(currX != NULL && currX->data!=x)
{
    prevX=currX;
    currX=currX->next;
}
//...
while(currY != NULL && currY->data!=y)
{
    prevY=currY;
    currY=currY->next;
}
```

So if for example `currX` is equal to `NULL` then the expression `currX->data!=x` will not be eva;luated.

This code snippet

```
struct node *swap = currY->next;
prevX->next = currY;
currY->next = prevY;
prevY->next = currX;
currX->next = swap;
```

is also wrong because for example `prevX` or `prevY` can be equal to `NULL`.

And you have to deal with the head in the function by reference. Otherwise the head node will not be changed.

You should split the function into two functions. The first one founds the node with the given value and the second one will swap found nodes if they are not equal to `NULL`.

Also it is a bad idea when functions depend on global variables. In fact your program can not deal with two lists simultaneously.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function swap can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{   
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node ** find( struct node **head, int data )
{
    while ( *head && ( *head )->data != data ) head = &( *head )->next;

    return head;
}

void swap( struct node **head, int data1, int data2 )
{
    struct node **left, **right;

    if ( *( left = find( head, data1 ) ) && *( right = find( head, data2 ) ) )
    {
        struct node *tmp = *left;
        *left = *right;
        *right = tmp;

        tmp = ( *left )->next;
        ( *left )->next = ( *right )->next;
        ( *right )->next = tmp;
    }
}

int push_front( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( struct node **head )
{
    for ( struct node *current = *head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->data );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    struct node *head = NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) push_front( &head, i );

    display( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i+=2 )
    {
        swap( &head, i, i + 1 );
    }

    display( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
8 9 6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1
```